# Modelsim: Debugging "NUMERIC_STD.TO_UNSIGNED: Vector truncated"

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I might be able to post some code if needed, it's hard though cause the code is on a different machine. But I'm looking more a general approach to debugging this warning "NUMERIC_STD.TO_UNSIGNED: Vector truncated" in a large project. The output looks like this:

```
Time: 2150217 ns Iteration: 3 Instance: ../chanmem
** Warning: NUMERIC_STD.TO_UNSIGNED: Vector truncated
```

And it's repeated for nearly the entire simulation. But my question is how to debug this? If I open the chanmem instance and search for "to_unsigned", it doesn't exist. It does have an unsigned input port but the signal driving that port never uses to_unsigned. So is there another way to isolate where the truncation is actually happening in Modelsim DE.

Thank you

Comment: The warning message is telling you you converted a natural integer to a binary value whose length cannot contain the entire binary value representing the natural (you've lost one or more leftmost 'bits'). Look where chanmem is instantiated at the port with the unsigned value and backward from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was an abnormal bug that was born around making a large number of changes at once. The code I inherited is using integers everywhere so to try to save on some resources I've been trying to simplify things down to using only unsigned operands. One thing I suppose I over looked is operations involving a global const integer and the new unsigned value. So there was things such as:

```
unsigned = (const integer)*(unsigned)
```

or

```
unsigned = (const integer) + (unsigned)
```

Not sure what I was expecting to happen here, but just overlooked the types I guess. So, i'm just going off of a huntch here, but I'm going to guess that the compiler was implicitly type casting the const integer to unsigned to perform the operation.

This is just a guess so someone feel free to correct it.

I was able to find it by using the "step" function in ModelSim which is usually a last resort for me becuase of how slow it can be. But in this case, I was able to narrow it down within about 30 mins or so.

Comment: Use ranged integers rather than integers, that gives you better control over word growth and truncation issues. (oh and there is no `const` in VHDL, only `constant` which actually IS constant)